# Webpage header is not full-width (Mobile View)

Tags: html, css

Could someone inspect my website and look into the header.

The problem is that when the website transitions into mobile, the header doesn't seem to go full width - there are some margins around the left and right.

I would love to have some advice.

Thank You,

Website is: http://blackbird.marketing

Comment: Just try `max-width: none;`, seems ok for me

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect your website, I see your site set max-width: 90% at @media screen and (max-width: 760px) and max-width: 96% at @media screen and (max-width: 1200px); You should reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be asking about this, as a developer, you must have the skills or the initiative to try to fix this by yourself.

This is what is happening:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) 

body .pagewidth,
body.full_width .themify_builder_row .row_inner,
body.full_width .related-posts,
.full_width .post-nav,
.full_width .commentwrap {
  /* max-width: 90% */
  max-width: 100%; // <- change the 90% to 100%
}
```

You also have 2px padding on the right, either you wrap it into a media query or change the `#headerwrap` directly

```
#headerwrap {
  /* padding-right: 2px; */
  padding-right: 0px; // <- change 2px to 0px
}
```